# make table layout with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

**Description**

I want to make table with the table data like this.

[image]

Let's look at the switch. In the first row or "Dashboard" have two form switch. and the rest have four form switch.

**Problem**

I've been tried to find best and effective solution but the result end like this :
[image]

Here's the code of the table :

```
import React from "react";
import { Table, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

const tableHeader = [
  "No",
  "Menu",
  "Sub Menu",
  "Lihat",
  "Tambah",
  "Ubah",
  "Hapus",
  "Export",
];

const submenu = [
  ["-"],
  ["Akun Pengguna", "Grup & Kontrol Hak Akses Akun", "Antrian Pasien", "Rawat Jalan"],
  ["Pemeriksaan Penunjang", "Rekam Medis", "Admisi Rawat Jalan"],
  ["Status dan Penempatan Kamar", "Transfer Pasien"],
];

let i = 1;

const tableDataMenu = [
  [i++, "Dashboard", submenu[0], "", null, null, null, ""],
  [i++, "Konfigurasi/Pengaturan", submenu[1], "", "", "", "", null],
  [i++, "Layanan Pasien", submenu[2], "", "", "", "", null],
  [i++, "Rawat Inap", submenu[3], "", "", "", "", null],
];

const FormCreateRole = () => {
  return (
    <Table>
      <thead style={{ backgroundColor: "#ECEFF1" }}>
        <tr>
          {tableHeader.map((header, index) => (
            <th
              key={index}
              className="txt-blue-grey-700 base-md text-bold text-center"
              style={{ padding: "0.75rem" }}
            >
              {header}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {tableDataMenu.map((row, idx) => (
        <React.Fragment key={idx}>
          <tr>
            {row.slice(0, 2).map((cell, idx) => (
              <td key={idx} className="text-center">{cell}</td>
            ))}
            <td>
              {row[2] && (
                <div>
                  {row[2].map((sub, idx) => (
                    <div key={idx} className="mb-3">{sub}</div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              )}
            </td>
            {row.slice(3).map((cell, idx) => {
                return (
                  <td key={idx}>
                    {row[2] &&
                      row[2].map((subIdx) => (
                        <div key={subIdx} className="mb-3 text-center">
                          <Form.Check type="switch" />
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    {cell}
                  </td>
                );
            })}
          </tr>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
};

export default FormCreateRole;
```

**Question**

1. How to fix the problem efficiently. So, the table react can match with the UI mockup ?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this block

```
{row.slice(3).map((cell, idx) => {
                return (
                  <td key={idx}>
                    {row[2] &&
                      row[2].map((subIdx) => (
                        <div key={subIdx} className="mb-3 text-center">
                          <Form.Check type="switch" />
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    {cell}
                  </td>
                );
            })}
```

You are saying:  "For each element in my row array, starting from index 3, create a new table cell containing a toggle switch, IF row[2] is truthy".  What you want to say is "For each element in my row array, starting from index 3, create a new table cell containing a toggle switch, IF the current element (cell) is truthy".  I believe something like the following will work, although I didn't test it so it may have some syntax errors or something of the like.

```
{row.slice(3).map((cell, idx) => {
            return (
              <td key={idx}>
                {row[2] &&
                  row[2].map((subIdx) => (cell !== null) && (
                    <div key={subIdx} className="mb-3 text-center">
                      <Form.Check type="switch" />
                    </div>
                  ))}
                {cell}
              </td>
            );
        })}
```

Comment: it works sir, but just only one row for each sub menu. i want to all submenu having form switch

Comment: Ahh I misunderstood the submenus; edited to hopefully fix the issue.  I will also mention that your line of code that is
`row[2].map((subIdx)...`, the `subIdx` is not going to be an index in this case, but rather the string value of the submenu item.  If you want the index, you need to do `row[2].map((submenu, subIdx)...` instead, as the first argument from `map` is always the array element, and the second is the index.

Comment: If I were you, I think I might extract the portion of the code that encapsulates all of the switch-drawing logic out into its own component - the code above is complex enough and has deep enough nesting that it's probably worth it, just for readability.